# Conceito de ataque Man-in-the-middle

Tags: segurança, arquitetura-de-software

Conceitualmente falando, o que é um ataque *Homem no meio*, mais comumente conhecido como *man-in-the-middle attack*?

Comment: @LucasNunes estava pensando em manter o "man-in-the-middle" no título, mesmo que tenha que tirar o "Homem  no Meio", porque é mais comum as pessoas procurarem por man-in-the-middle ou MitM do que "Homem no meio". Alguém mais tem sugestão de qual melhor título nesse caso?

Comment: Eu removi porque o título ficou estava poluído. Mas concordo com você, é melhor deixar o termo mais comum para ajudar.

Answer (score 10):

Genericamente falando, é um ataque onde toda a comunicação entre Alice e Bob é interceptada e eventualmente modificada por um agente hostil, "Charlie". Alice e Bob pensam que estão falando um com o outro mas estão ambos falando com Charlie, que se faz passar pelos dois.

O ataque MITM pode ocorrer mesmo que Alice e Bob troquem chaves públicas (como no SSL), porque Charlie pode substituir as chaves no início da sessão.

Uma defesa é certificar a origem das chaves públicas. No caso do SSL, tem aquele aviso do browser quando uma chave não é assinada por uma Autoridade Certificadora conhecida. Dificilmente Charlie teria um certificado SSL assinado e atrelado ao domínio correto.

Outra defesa é Alice e Bob trocarem chaves (públicas ou privadas) por algum outro meio seguro, antes de estabelecer comunicação. Charlie pode interceptar a comunicação mas não conhece o segredo compartilhado antes.

Answer (score 5):

Tecnicamente falando, quando você configura as rotas do seu computador para chegar no gateway da rede. Que no caso, poderia ser seu modem da velox, ou GVT. Para enviar um pacote pela rede, o seu computador envia para o modem, ou switch, um MAC Address. E é feito uma requisição "who has", que pergunta em qual MAC está aquele ip.

Um exemplo seria o computador com ip 192.168.0.2 tem o MAC X, e ele quer enviar uma requisição para o gateway de ip 192.168.0.254 com o MAC Y. Feito isso, será perguntado na rede quem tem o ip 192.168.0.254, e o seu modem vai responder que ele que está com esse ip. Desse modo, você acessará internet normalmente. Seu computador têm uma tabela chamada ARP(Address Resolution Protocol), que guarda ip's com seus determinados mac's. Em um curto intervalo de tempo, a mesma pergunta é feita na rede para sempre atualizar a tabela ARP. Os computadores são configurados por padrão para dizer a verdade, ou seja, o computador com IP 192.168.0.3 com MAC Z, foi configurado para sempre dizer isso. Mas eu posso simplesmente mentir para a rede, eu posso dizer que o ip 192.168.0.254 está no MAC Z. Ocasionando assim, um redirecionamento do tráfego de rede para a máquina de ip 192.168.0.3. E o que essa máquina irá fazer, é deixar que os dados continuem(FORWARD) para o gateway, e quando houver resposta, o ip 192.168.0.3 entregará para o ip que fez a requisição em primeiro momento.

Lembrando que os equipamentos físicos que transportam rede, switch, modens e hubs, não conhecem ip's, só conhecem MAC Address.