# RSA, SSLStream - Key Exchange

Tags: c#, criptografia, sslstream, rsa

Bom pessoal, estou utilizando SSLStream para fazer a comunicação entre um client e server, utilizando OPENSSL.
E esse meu client, é uma máquina(digi), que como requisito tem que utilizar criptografia RSA.
Então eu tenho que fazer uma troca de chaves públicas entre client e server. 
Eu estava fazendo testes para essa troca de uma maneira que não considero a certa, mas estava fazendo dessa maneira, porque fiz um client específico para fazer isso localhost ou em qualquer outra máquina que não fosse a máquina que eu vou utilizar realmente(a minha digi).
Eu estava fazendo dessa maneira, ambas as pontas enviam a chave pública dessa maneira:

```
byte[] modulus = pubkey.Modulus;
sslStream.Write(modulus, 0, modulus.Length);
sslStream.Flush();
```

E ambas as pontas recebem dessa maneira:

```
 byte[] exponent = {1, 0, 1};
 byte[] modulus = new byte[256];
 sslStream.Read(modulus, 0, modulus.Length);

 clientPublicKey.D = null;
 clientPublicKey.DP = null;
 clientPublicKey.DQ = null;
 clientPublicKey.Exponent = exponent;
 clientPublicKey.InverseQ = null;
 clientPublicKey.Modulus = modulus;
 clientPublicKey.P = null;
 clientPublicKey.Q = null;
```

Mas ao testar na máquina (digi) essa mesma solução, cheguei a conclusão que essa troca de chaves não é feita dessa mesma maneira.

Tem alguma outra maneira de fazer essa troca de chaves? Porque no próprio objeto do RSA e SSLSTREAM tem uma propriedade `KeyExchangeAlgorithm`.

Answer (score 2):

> Vou responder de maneira bem geral, pois não tenho familiaridade com `SslStream` (ou mesmo C# em geral), mas creio que há alguns equívocos nessa pergunta que eu posso ajudar a esclarecer.

A ideia por trás de se usar um canal de comunicações seguro é que todo conteúdo trocado por esse canal esteja protegido (confidencial, autenticado, íntegro). Se isso não fosse verdade, então não haveria sentido em se usar um **SSL** Stream - bastaria se usar simplesmente um Stream...

Dessa forma, os passos necessários para se assegurar a segurança de um canal ("aperto de mão", ou *handshake*) são **externos** ao uso desse canal. Não faz sentido você utilizar o próprio `SslStream` para enviar coisas como a chave de criptografia, pois no momento em que esse stream está "usável" se assume que o *hanshake* (e portanto a troca de chaves) já foi feito com sucesso.

Sua conclusão de que a troca de chaves não é feita dessa maneira é, portanto, acertada. Bem como sua observação de que há propriedades [e métodos] relacionados ao *handshake* nas próprias classes da biblioteca. A maneira correta de se usar um `SslStream` é utilizar seus próprios métodos para se fazer a troca de chaves (e protocolo de *handshake*) e só começar a transmitir dados por ela quando esse processo estiver concluído  com sucesso.

Abrindo um parêntese: segundo [a documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.security.sslstream.canread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a própria classe se assegura de permanecer ilegível enquanto o *handshake* não for concluído com sucesso:

> **Propriedade SslStream::CanRead**
>
> Obtém um valor de Boolean que indica se o fluxo subjacente é legível.
>
> **true** se a autenticação ocorreu e o fluxo subjacente são legíveis; se não **false**.

Quanto à maneira correta de se fazer esse *handshake*, vou deixar para quem entende melhor de C# responder. Uma passada de olho na documentação sugere o método [`AuthenticateAsServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms145064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e suas variantes. O que me leva ao último equívoco:

> Então eu tenho que fazer uma troca de chaves públicas entre client e server.

Não é uma troca de **chaves** que você precisa fazer, mas sim uma troca de **certificados**. A chave sozinha garante apenas a confidencialidade de uma comunicação, mas não sua autenticidade. Se o client receber uma chave do server e usá-la para se comunicar confidencialmente, ele estará seguro que nenhum *eavesdropper* (espião, escuta) estará interceptando a comunicação e lendo seu conteúdo. Mas ele não tem como ter certeza de **com quem** ele está se comunicando.

Um server falso (ex.: num [ataque "Man-in-the-Middle"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_man-in-the-middle)) poderia enviar a chave **dele** para o client - em vez da chave do server real - de modo a fazer com que o client se comunique com ele achando que está se comunicando com o server real. Da mesma forma, ele pode enviar a chave dele ao server real, fazendo se passar pelo client. No fim das contas, em vez da comunicação ser:

```
client real <----> server real
```

ela será:

```
client real <----> server falso, também client falso <----> server real
```

O que destrói todas as garantias de segurança que o protocolo SSL em princípio te daria. A solução (uma das soluções, porém a única que é comumente usada na prática) é criar um "certificado de segurança", que nada mais é que uma chave pública associada a uma **identidade** e ambas **assinadas** por uma entidade de confiança (*trusted third-party*) - estabelecida de comum acordo.

Uma descrição completa do que é um certificado e de como usá-lo corretamente (às vezes só o server usa, às vezes o client também) seria por demais extensa para essa resposta, por isso sugiro você se informar melhor sobre como ele funciona. Pode até mesmo ser através de uma pergunta separada no próprio SOpt (tivemos [perguntas semelhantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7051/215) no passado), através da qual eu estaria disposto a aprofundar mais no assunto.

Comment: Observação: estou assumindo que quando você diz "meu client, é uma máquina(digi), que como requisito tem que utilizar criptografia RSA" você quer dizer que ela usa o protocolo SSL. SSL e RSA são coisas diferentes - é possível usar SSL com - por exemplo - Curvas Elípticas em vez do RSA, da mesma forma que é possível usar RSA puro, sem SSL (com chaves trocadas anteriormente - *pre-exchanged keys* - ou num esquema de "Web of Trust"). Se minha interpretação estiver equivocada, favor esclarecer melhor a pergunta.

Comment: a parte do authenticateAsServer e authenticateAsClient já está feita, o caso mesmo é a troca de chaves por causa do RSA

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi Nesse caso, estou confuso: você já tem um canal seguro de comunicação estabelecido, mas ainda precisa fazer troca de chaves?! Que protocolo é esse que você está usando? Tem como postar alguma referência, um link sobre o assunto?

Comment: deixo explicar melhor, realmente deixei mal explicado

Comment: eu fiz essa comunicação segura, mas mesmo assim utilizando o a criptografia RSA(algorítimo que possui 2 chaves, uma privada e uma publica), eu necessito enviar essa chave pública para minha outra ponta, para que ela possa encriptar com essa minha chave que enviei

Comment: da mesma maneira que eu preciso receber a chave publica da outra ponta, para encriptar as informações para enviar para ela.

Comment: SSlStream - http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: RSA - http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi Nesse caso, a comunicação já é confidencial. Não é necessário - do ponto de vista da comunicação - encriptar mais nada, pois ela já está encriptada. Você pode ter outras razões para adicionar uma camada adicional de criptografia (ex.: se o client for mandar algo para o server **indiretamente** - através de um outro canal não protegido por SSL), caso contrário essa troca adicional de chaves acrescenta zero de segurança adicional. Nota: não estou questionando a pergunta, você pode ter suas próprias razões para fazer isso; nesse caso, vou deixar que quem entenda melhor de C# responda.

Comment: sim, eu também tenho o mesmo ponto de vista, mas as especificações estão me dizendo para fazer isso, esse é o ponto.