# Como funciona o algoritmo de criptografia RSA?

Tags: algoritmo, segurança, criptografia, rsa

Eu queria entender como funciona o algoritmo **RSA**, passo a passo,  para uma melhor compreensão e para que eu possa utilizá-lo de maneira adequada.

Comment: Estou votando pra reabrir, pois o RSA é simples o suficiente para ser explicado em uma resposta (ainda que a álgebra completa não o seja). Perguntas semelhantes foram feitas e permaneceram abertas ([exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43492/215), [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43495/215), [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43493/215), [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105665/215)), e pela minha experiência esses algoritmos descritos nas outras perguntas são ainda bem mais complexos que o RSA.

Comment: Adoraria que a pergunta fosse reaberta. :/